# AngularJS ng-include src header?

Tags: angularjs

Is there something I can check on server side if a URL that is called for a src-attribute from a ng-include?

Example: `<ng-include src="'login.html'">`

Like when you can check headers if a request is Ajax. So the call must be done with Ajax-header present.
This because I wanna prevent that people can also call the url /login.html and see the output.

I checked if it was working when a Ajax-header was present, but I got a 405 always, so it wasn't working.

Comment: You can always check the `http_referrer`.

Comment: curious what problem you are trying to solve. Can also use httpInterceptors to add authorization headers

Comment: You can also set a default header that all your angular requests get that you analyze on the backend. Of course, none of this is super secure, but it makes it harder for people to just hit the link. `$http.defaults.headers.common.IsXHR = 'yes'`